# Escaping values in an LDAP search

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I have the following code which allows me to search for a group by its `SamAaccountName`:

```
public static DirectoryEntry GetGroup(string groupSamName)
{
    string sFilter = "(&(objectClass=group)" +
        "(objectCategory=Group)" +
        "(SAMAccountName=" + groupSamName + "))";

    // find group
    SearchResult srGroup = SearchOne(sFilter, null);

    if (srGroup == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("AD Group '" + groupSamName + "' not found.");
    }

    DirectoryEntry deGroup = srGroup.GetDirectoryEntry();

    return deGroup;
}

private static SearchResult SearchOne(string sFilter, string[] propertiesToLoad)
{
    DirectoryEntry deDomain = GetADDomain();

    // create directory searcher
    DirectorySearcher dsSearch = new DirectorySearcher(deDomain);
    dsSearch.CacheResults = false;
    dsSearch.Filter = sFilter;

    if (propertiesToLoad != null && propertiesToLoad.Length > 0)
    {
        dsSearch.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(propertiesToLoad);
    }

    SearchResult sr = dsSearch.FindOne();

    return sr;
}
```

If I wanted to search by a `SamAccountName` of `__Test (Test Group) - Restricted`, it actually works, when I would have expected that the parenthesis would have broken the search syntax.

What do I need to escape and what do I not need to escape?

Answer (score 0):

It works only because you have opening and closing parentheses and it can figure out that the whole thing is part of the condition. However, if you only have an opening *or* closing parenthesis, like this:

```
(&(objectClass=group)(objectCategory=group)(sAMAccountName=__Test (Test Group - Restricted))
```

It will break.

To avoid this, you can escape parentheses in all cases. [This article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx), under the "Special Characters" heading, describes which characters should be escaped and how to do it. In your case, you'd replace `(` with `\28` and `)` with `\29`:

```
(&(objectClass=group)(objectCategory=group)(sAMAccountName=__Test \28Test Group\29 - Restricted))
```